# Getting AttributeError while loading and accessing the data using csv.reader()

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, numpy

Below is the code while running the code, getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'.

```
import csv
import numpy
def loadCsv(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(filename,"r"))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset
filename = 'data1.csv'
dataset = loadCsv(filename)
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows').format(filename, len(dataset))
```

Comment: `print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows').format(filename, len(dataset))` should be `print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows'.format(filename, len(dataset)))`  - `format` is a string method.

Comment: The trace stack should say what object is `NoneType`, which is something you should have included in your question.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows').format(filename, len(dataset))
```

to this

```
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows'.format(filename, len(dataset)))
```

you get the error because you try to apply `.format` to the `print`-function, whereas it is a method which needs to be applied to a string.

Comment: Extra parentheses must be added to the print statement.

Comment: this is not true!

Comment: Check that out once extra parentheses must be added for sure.

Comment: More precisely, `print` is a function *that returns `None`*. If had returned a string, this error wouldn't appear.